# Running the "if else" query

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I run the following query :

```
select field1 f1, field2 f2, case when field3 >1 and field 4 > 0 than field3 else field4 as f34, field5 f5
```

This query dosn`t work (I get syntax error near case)
What is the correct way to implement if else in sql?

Comment: case when field3 > 1 and field4 > 0 then field3 else field4 end as [f34] .. you forgot 'end' to close to case

Comment: `than` -> `then`? Also which database system, not all of them support a conditional case (some only support searched case)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel . . . What databases don't support conditional case but do support searched case?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I haven't been confronted with it in a while, but I seem to recall that either Access or FoxPro was missing it, and from that I assume that there are probably others that are missing it to (especially some of the older systems that are no longer actively developed).

Comment: You wrote `than` instead of `then`, and you forgot to terminate the `CASE` statement with an `END` (between `field4` and `as`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select field1 f1, field2 f2, 
   (case when field3 >1 and field 4 > 0 then field3 
    else field4 end) as f34, 
   field5 f5
```

You had a typo (`than`) and I have also formatted it to be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Some typo, and not closing the CASE with the END:

```
select field1 f1, 
       field2 f2, 
       case when field3 >1 and field 4 > 0 then 
           field3 
       else 
           field4 
       end as f34, 
       field5 f5
```

Answer (score 0):

FROM is missing, then instead of than, END for case is missing:

```
SELECT field1 f1
    ,field2 f2
    ,CASE 
        WHEN field3 > 1
            AND field4 > 0
            THEN field3
        ELSE field4
        END AS f34
    ,field5 f5
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was a typo, try

`SELECT field1 f1, 
    field2 f2, 
    (case when field3 >1 and field 4 > 0 then field3 else field4) as f34,
    field5 f5 
FROM table`